# Python's sum not returning same result as NumPy's numpy.sum

Tags: python, numpy

Numpy's sum function is returning the correct expected result, but the default python's sum is not (at least not for uint8 datatype, which makes it even more confusing):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np                                                      

In [2]: x = np.random.randint(2, size = (1000,100))                             

In [3]: x                                                                       
Out[3]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, ..., 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, ..., 1, 0, 1],
       ...,
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, ..., 1, 1, 1]])

In [4]: np.sum(x)                                                               
Out[4]: 50318

In [5]: sum(sum(x))                                                             
Out[5]: 50318

In [6]: x = x.astype('uint8')                                                   

In [7]: np.sum(x)                                                               
Out[7]: 50318

In [8]: sum(sum(x))                                                             
Out[8]: 16014
```

Comment: Sounds like integer overflow somewhere but I can't tell where

Comment: Have you tried this with smaller arrays, ones you can print out and add up yourself to verify?

Comment: I tried it (python's built in sum) on a few small arrays and it works for those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By specifying `uint8` you are telling numpy to use 8 bits per element. The maximum number that can be stored in 8 bits is 255. So when you sum, you get an overflow.
Practical example:

```
>>> arr = np.array([[255],[1]],dtype=np.uint8)
>>> arr
array([[255],
       [1]], dtype=uint8)
>>> sum(arr)
array([0], dtype=uint8)
>> arr[0]+arr[1]
array([0], dtype=uint8)
```

Note that `sum(arr)` corresponds to `arr[0] + arr[1]` in this case.  As stated in the docs:

> Arithmetic is modular when using integer types, and no error is raised on overflow.

Comment: Why doesn't `np.sum` overflow in this case?

Comment: It seems to cast automatically to `np.uint64`

Comment: `type(np.sum(x))` returns `<class 'numpy.uint64'>` but I see that
`type(sum(sum(x)))` returns `<class 'numpy.int64'>` so it is also casting it to a large int, so still confused as to why one overflows but not the other?

Comment: The overflow occurs in the inner sum: `type(sum(arr)) <class 'numpy.ndarray'> `. Indeed, `np.sum(sum(arr))` would also return the wrong result. `np.sum` should be element-wise, while the inner `sum()` would use the add operation on arrays.